# how to assign same id for a same name (string) like dense rank to a character field in Excel

Tags: excel, grouping, rank

I want a dense_rank kind of formula which will return a same id for a same name in first field.  Now the problem is that `rank` or `rank.eq` function in excel can be applied to value fields only but here I want a dense rank for each name.

I leave an example...

[image]

thanks for your help

Comment: You need to add a whole lot more to this but Countif could be used

Comment: and how I do it? @Marcucciboy2

Comment: You need to post what you have tried yourself, that is the expectation on StackOverflow.

Comment: The Excel help / formula builder shows examples of countif() in use - try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to assign unique ID to each name use this formula in `G1` (assuming your data is in `F1:F16` like the screenshot below

[image]

**Approach-1** use this formula in `G1` onwards(down)

```
=COUNTIF($F$1:$F$16, "<="&F1)
```

Still if you want these numbers to start from 1 and keep on increasing so on use this formula in `H1`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((G1>=$G$1:$G$16)/COUNTIF($G$1:$G$16,$G$1:$G$16))
```

**APPROACH-2** Without the need for creating intermediate field

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F1>=$F$1:$F$16)/COUNTIF($F$1:$F$16,$F$1:$F$16))
```

You can get results like this

[image]